# JUnit: how to test method which deletes entity (JPA)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have simple crud repository:

```
public interface BookRepository extends CrudRepository<Book, Long> {
    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    void deleteById(Long id);
}
```

How can I write simple JUnit test to check if this method works fine? Of course, in this case, I have entity `Book`

Comment: if you are using springboot you can use DataJpaTest annotation which run an embedded h2 database and test your repository. but as said below you dont have to test the spring data library, it should work fine :)

Answer (score 5):

**You should not.**

Unit testing Spring Data repositories is a problem of Spring Data developers - as a developer you are using their API and it should working that's all. Care about your logic not the library - focus on integration tests

Anyway if you really want to do this - what I would do would be to mock `EntityManager` and somehow inject it to the `Repository` implementation (sounds like horrible task), or I would use [DBUnit](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/) test, prepare test data and simply would check whether object was deleted (this would be prefered way)

Answer (score 1):

Usually Spring Data repositories do not tests, but If you really want to test it you can use `@DataJpaTest` and inject `TestEntityManager`.

Example:

```
@DataJpaTest
class BookRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private BookRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager em;

    @Test
    void deleteById() {
        Book book = ...;
        final Long id = em.persistAndGetId(book, Long.class);
        repository.deleteById(id);
        em.flush();
        Book after = em.find(Book.class, id);
        assertThat(after).isNull();
    }
}
```

Idea is that you use `TestEntityManager` for all operation exclude your. In the example you are persist and find entity via `TestEntityManager` but delete via your custom repository.